# How do I change the name of 2 or more columns using the same dataset

Tags: sql, sqlite

My goal is to get both the Station Start and Station End Codes to be it's original name using the A_Statn Dataset.

What I **expect** is:
[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1INiT.png)

What I **got** was:
[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H57px.png)

The **problem** is: I can only change 1 column's codename to it's original name.

The main dataset that I used: [Main Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Wbo.png)

The other dataset that I used to join and change the code name for Station Start is:
[Other Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bCdq.png)

What I have tried which I got an error:

```
-- t1 = Trans
-- t2 = Station
-- t3 = cust


select t3.NAME  as 'Name', (
case
    when t3.AGE <20 then 'Student'
    when t3.AGE <40 then 'Adult'
    else 'Senior'
end
) as 'Age Group', t3.GENDER as 'Gender', t2.STN_DESC as 'Station Start', t1.STN_END as 'Station End'
from t1
join t3 on t1.CAN_NUM = t3.CAN_NUM
join t2 on t1.STN_ST = t2.STN_CODE
join t2 on t1.STN_END = t2.STN_CODE


order by (
case
    when t3.AGE <20 then 1
    when t3.AGE <40 then 2
    else 3
end
),3
;
```

The error that I got came from:

> join t2 on t1.STN_ST = t2.STN_CODE

> join t2 on t1.STN_END = t2.STN_CODE

The blocks looks like this: [Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJL92.png)

Is there a way to use the other dataset to change 2 columns of the main dataset?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the table twice with different aliases to get the desired result -

```
select t3.NAME  as 'Name', 
       (case when t3.AGE <20 then 'Student'
             when t3.AGE <40 then 'Adult'
             else 'Senior'
        end) as 'Age Group',
       t3.GENDER as 'Gender',
       t4.STN_DESC as 'Station Start',
       t5.STN_DESC as 'Station End'
from t1
join t3 on t1.CAN_NUM = t3.CAN_NUM
join t2 t4 on t1.STN_ST = t4.STN_CODE
join t2 t5 on t1.STN_END = t5.STN_CODE
order by (case when t3.AGE <20 then 1
               when t3.AGE <40 then 2
          else 3 end), 3;
```